# File sharing via local network from multiple device to a single iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sockets, server

I would like to make an app that can be used to share files from multiple devices(can be iPhone and android) to a single iPhone without Internet. What will be the possible solutions for it?

Created a HTTP Server on iPhone with [library](https://github.com/swhitty/FlyingFox). But i need a socket server.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [Multipeer Connectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity), just found out about it myself.